# Access json $values variable with Elsa Workflow designer

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, elsa-workflows

I have this json object saved to a variable in elsa workflow designer.

```
{
  "users": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "$type": "System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Linq.Expressions",
        "UsersID": 2,
        "AssociatedUsersID": 51,
        "UserEmail": "bob@Site.com",
        "Title": "Manager",
        "UserFirstName": "Bob",
        "UserLastName": "Loblaw",
        "NotificationTypes": {
          "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib",
          "$values": [
            "Vendor Assigned"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to access the "$values" collection in the object for the "ForEach" activity in the designer, but I keep getting errors. Elsa's documentation is scant to say the least. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
getVariable('users')
getVariable('users').$values
getVariable('users')["$values"]
getVariable('users')['$values']
```

All result in errors. What am I doing wrong here?

```
If I just refer to the users variable I get this:
 "name": "Items",
      "value": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib",
        "$values": [
          {
            "$ref": "3"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: It seems like it's an issue with property names starting with the $ sign, can you rename your variables starting with $ and see if it works fine?